# find lines from one file in another efficiently

Tags: search, optimization

I have two files referencing some objects, the first file contains a label and a corresponding id value on each line as follows:

```
label : 123456789
anotherlabel : 987654321
yetanotherlabel : 567891234
```

The second file contains a subset of records from file one that meet certain criteria, but it only lists the ID. It's a flat one column list as follows

```
987654321
123456789
```

I want to make a third file that will contain one column listing the labels from the first file that correspond to the ids from the second file. So in this example it would be

```
anotherlabel
label
```

These files are fairly big so I'm looking for an efficient solution. How should I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can upload file 2 into hashtable(if it fit into the memory), and thereafter iterate file 1, and parse. If ID match, then print for appropriate ID.

Comment: The problem with this is that the IDs aren't unique, and I want to add all labels associated to a given id. Should have mentioned that earlier, sorry!